# Solution Bootstrap form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap validation for validating jsp page .

my folder structure is as follow,

```
WebContent
├── bootstrap-form-validation
├── js
└── pages
```

Here all three folders are under web content.  If i create one more folder called teacherDetails under pages folder for placing my jsp files. My problem is the validation is not working properly. but when I put that jsp file out of pages folder or under webcontent directly its working fine, for my project it has to be in pages folder . please help me in this and my jsp code is as follow

```
 <html lang="en">
  <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Bootstrap, from Twitter</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<!-- Le styles -->
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- Optional theme -->
 <link href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/twitter-bootstrap/twitter-bootstrap-v2/docs/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
  <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/bootstrap-form-validation/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

 <link href="css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/bootstrap-datetimepicker-master/css/datetimepicker.css">
  <script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/twitter-bootstrap/twitter-bootstrap-v2/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
     <script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/bootstrap-datetimepicker-master/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
</head> 


 <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker({
        pickTime : false
    });
});
 </script>


   <script>
        $(function () { $("input,select,textarea").not("[type=submit]").jqBootstrapValidation(); } );
  </script>


   <script>
function profileDetails() {
    document.getElementById("profiledetails").submit();

}
function profileCancel() {
    document.getElementById("profileDetails").reset();
}
   </script>




    <style>

   .no-space [class *="span"] {
margin-left: 0 !important;
width: 25% !important;
//
This
is
for
4
elements
ONLY
in
the
row
     }


   </style>


     <body>






        <form class="well form-horizontal" id="create_teacher" method="post" action="">
            <div style="height: 850px;">
                <div style="width: 104%; margin-top: -20px;">

                    <fieldset>
                        <legend style="color: #333;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Teacher Information</legend>
                </div>
                <br> <br>
                <div style="margin-left: 140px">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="uln" class="control-label">Teacher Id:</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="teacherId"
                                id="teacherId">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br> 
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="control-label">Name :</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                        <div class="col-lg-8">

                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="teacherName"
                                id="teacherName">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br> 

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="gender" class="control-label">Gender:</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                        <div class="col-lg-8">

                            <select class="form-control" name="gender">
                                <option></option>
                                <option>Male</option>
                                <option>Female</option>

                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <br> 



                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="dob" class="control-label">Date Of Birth(DOB) :</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="dob" id="date">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br> 

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="dob" class="control-label">Date Of
                        Join:</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="doj" id="date">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br> 

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="control-label">Education
                        :</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                        <div class="col-lg-8">

                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="teacherName"
                                id="education">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br> 

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="control-label">Experience
                        :</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                        <div class="col-lg-8">

                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="teacherName"
                                id="experience">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br> 

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="control-label">Prev Employee details :</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                        <div class="col-lg-8">

                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="teacherName"
                                id="prevdetails">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br> 


                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Photo :</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                        <div class="col-lg-8">

                            <input type="file"  />
                        </div>
                    </div>



                </div>
                <br> 

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="control-label">Email Id:</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                        <div class="col-lg-8">

                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="teacherName"
                                id="email">
                                <p class="help-block"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br> 
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label"></label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <div style="margin-left: 150px">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit"
                                onclick="profileDetails();" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Cancel"
                                onclick="cancelProfile();" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </form>


   <script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/bootstrap-form-validation/assets/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script> 

    <script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/bootstrap-form-validation/assets/js/jquery.validate.js"></script> 

    <script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/script.js"></script> 
 <script>
    addEventListener('load', prettyPrint, false);
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('pre').addClass('prettyprint linenums');
        });
     </script> 
</body>
 </html>
```

Comment: where did you place your bootstrap files? please provide the full folder structure.

Comment: open console and check which resources failed to load...

Comment: bootstrap is above the bootstrap-form-validation folder

Comment: how to open console . . actually I check the source code from browser clicked on each link . . all r working fine . . all are loading . .

Comment: in browser right click > inspect element, there you'll find console.
what is the value of `<%=request.getContextPath()%>` it will always be  
a fixed or will be the folder where the current page is?

Comment: getContextPath() showing my project name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your links are relative

```
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

these links will search for the mentioned folder in the same level.
so if you put your jsp's in some folder called teacherDetails under pages, it'll look for bootstrap folder inside pages folder.

so to point to folders outside the current level, you've to specify it as follows:

```
<link href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
./ represents the current folder, ../ will represent the parent of current folder and so on..
```

Comment: Ya I did it but its not working , and for validation it has to search validator rt.